# how to distinguish Dynamically created datatable in onrowaction method

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

we have a requirement to create as many lightning datables in LWC as the number of quote lines dynamically increases.
Below is the code I wrote to determine which datatable we have picked using the getSelectedName function. I have put the title to the datatable but am unable to retrieve the name. Could you kindly assist me in determining how to differentiate between different data-tables?

mycomponent.html

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
        <ol class="slds-list_ordered">
            <template iterator:it={quoteEntitlementProducts.data}> 
                <li key={it.value}>     
                    <div class="slds-scope"> 
                        <p class="slds-text-heading_label slds-m-bottom_small"> Select the assest for entitlement - {it.value} </p>
                    </div>
                    <lightning-datatable data ={data} columns = {columns} key-field="Id" onrowselection={getSelectedName} selected-rows={autoSelectedrow} title={it.value} onheaderaction={onselect}></lightning-datatable>
                    <br>
                </li>
            </template>
        </ol>
        <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;">
            <lightning-button variant="neutral" title="ConfirmSelection" class="slds-float_right" icon-name="utility:send"
                icon-position="left" onclick={handleclick} label="ConfirmSelection" disabled={isSaved}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</template>
```

mycomponent.js

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire, track } from 'lwc';
import queryQuotelineitems from '@salesforce/apex/NF_AssestRetrieval.queryQuotelineitems';
import getAssestsfromAccount from '@salesforce/apex/NF_AssestRetrieval.getAssestsfromAccount';
export default class AssestforEntitlements extends LightningElement {
    @api paramValue;
    @track data;
    @track columns = [ 
        {label:'AccountName',fieldName:'AccountName',type:'text',sortable: true},
        {label:'Asset',fieldName:'Name',type:'text',sortable: true}
       // {label:'AssetId',fieldName:'Id',type:'text',}
    ];
    autoSelectedrow = [];
    quoteEntitlementProducts = new Array();
    @wire(queryQuotelineitems,{ quoteid:'$paramValue'})
    quoteEntitlementProducts
    @wire(getAssestsfromAccount,{ quoteid:'$paramValue'}) Assestdetails({error,data})
    {
        if(data)
        {
            let preparedArr = [];
            data.forEach(record => {
                let preparedRec = {};
                preparedRec.AccountName = record.Account.Name;
                preparedRec.Name = record.Name;
                preparedRec.Id = record.Id;
                preparedArr.push(preparedRec);
            });
            this.data = preparedArr;
            this.autoSelectedrow = preparedArr;
        }
        else if(error)
        {
            this.data = 'undefined';
        }
    }
    getSelectedName(event) {
        const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
        // Display that fieldName of the selected rows
        for (let i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
            console.log('You selected: ' + selectedRows[i].Id);
            console.log(event.title);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the Id in the selectedRows[i].Id, you can perform a search function on the this.data collection and look for the name.
You can also try to pass a new data-name parameter. You can after retrieve this parameter value as follows: event.target.dataset.name;

Comment: Thank you @Alin Paraschiv for your response but the same data set is  begin used in all the dynamically created lightning datatables.so it gives same name for all the tables

Comment: In your wire function you have this code block
`data.forEach(record => {
        let preparedRec = {};
        preparedRec.AccountName = record.Account.Name;
        preparedRec.Name = record.Name;
        preparedRec.Id = record.Id;
        preparedArr.push(preparedRec);
    });`
Assuming that selectedRows[i].Id = preparedRec.Id I don't see why you can't run a search function over that array in order to match these 2 Ids. Once matched you have your name

Comment: sorry my question is how to distinguish different data tables not rows in that data table

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. than maybe try using the key={it.value} on the datatable and instead of the value, use some unique identifier for each datatable